# StoredProcedure executes in SSMS, not in VB.NET application (no SqlException thrown)

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I have a SQL StoredProcedure that performs two `INSERT INTO` operations in SSMS as expected. 
When executing this SP in my VB.NET application, it is executing (no `SqlException` thrown in `Try` block) but not executing the `INSERT INTO` commands.
This application uses numerous SP's that all work without problems.

Code is as follows:

```
            Using (ParentMDI.dbCon)
                Dim sqlcmd As New SqlCommand("hyd_top_level_isr")
                With sqlcmd
                    .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@part_num", part_num)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@issue", issue)
                End With
                Try
                    sql.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Catch ex As SqlException
                    If DialogResult.Yes = MessageBox.Show("Error inserting top-level ISR." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Send Error Report?", "Workflow Error", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation) Then
                        ParentMDI.emailerrorstring = "Stored Procedure: hyd_top_level_isr"
                        ParentMDI.emailerrormessage = ex.Message
                        ParentMDI.ErrorEmail()
                    End If
                End Try
            End Using
```

For clarification;

I have inserted breakpoints before `ExecuteNonQuery()`. The sub does execute the `ExecuteNonQuery()` and the parameters being passed are populated with the correct values.
I have also inserted a `RETURN` in the SP to return the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`. This returns an empty string (not `NULL`, as I was expecting).

If any of you need more information, please let me know.
I will be massively appreciative of anyone who can educate me on where I'm going wrong!

(This is my first time ever asking for help, please be kind!) :)

EDIT:
Sorry guys. I seem to have lead you on incorrectly. The code pasted above is me trying all sorts of different attempts at trying to solve this. What I'll post now is what I should have posted in the first place. With the same outcome. Sorry for the confusion, and thanks for your attempts so far...

```
            Dim sqlcmd As New SqlCommand("hyd_top_level_isr", ParentMDI.dbCon)
            With sqlcmd
                    .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@part_num", part_num)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@issue", issue)
                End With
            Try
                sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Catch ex As SqlException
                If DialogResult.Yes = MessageBox.Show("Error inserting top-level ISR." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Send Error Report?", "Workflow Error", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation) Then
                    ParentMDI.emailerrorstring = "Stored Procedure: hyd_top_level_isr"
                    ParentMDI.emailerrormessage = ex.Message
                    ParentMDI.ErrorEmail()
                End If
            End Try
```

Comment: Can you please share the ex.Message you're getting?

Comment: I see a couple of mistakes in your code, but non of them should lead to the problem you described. First mistake is using a "global" `SqlConnection` instance. You should be using `SqlConnection` as a local variable inside a `using` statement. Second mistake is not wrapping the `SqlCommand` with the `using` statement. The third problem, and the one that might actually solve this issue, is the use of [`AddWithValue`](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). You should use `Add` instead.

Comment: @PedroMartins The OP clearly states no SQL Exception was thrown....

Comment: Are you calling the correct statement? Shouldn't you use sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery() instead of sql.ExecuteNonQuery()?

Comment: I cannot see sqlcmd used.  And what is sql object?

Comment: 1) It appears that the command doesn't have a connection associated with it. 2) You need to Open the connection before executing the query and then close (and dispose of) it afterwards.

Comment: Hi guys, I've made an edit, please see above. @Pedro-martins, you are correct, I was made an edit to the SqlCommand name in the post, and forgot to change the Execture statement.

Comment: What did you see in Sql Profiler when you ran your VB program?  How are you verifying that it is not working?  Are you sure you're looking in the right database?

Comment: I'm verifying it's not working, as it doesn't perform the insert into the tables. Also by returning the SCOPE_IDENTITY() returns a blank string, so nothing inserted. As for the database, yes. All data is stored in the same database. Also if I wasn't looking at the right database, surely it would fail the Try and reach the Catch block?

Comment: Can you share stored procedure also?

Comment: Without sounding like I'm palming you off, I don't know how that is going to help. The SP works. It executes in SSMS by passing the two parameters being passed in the VB.NET application. It's literally two simple INSERT INTO statements. I am 100% sure the problem lies either in VB or somewhere inbetween. Thanks!

Comment: @jaygale23 I strongly recommend that you do not use AddWithValue.

Comment: Could I ask why? I've ben using AddWithValue without a problem for years.

Comment: I had a similar sounding issue last week. After the team investigated, it appeared that the ODBC driver is returning too early, losing the SQL results. The temporary solution was to split the stored proc in two, one for creating a view containing all the data, and one for accessing it. In our situation it was the same, stored proc works fine in SSMS, through code it fails.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Zohar Peled's comment I think you should set sqlCmd's connection and use sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery. Below you should also use local sqlConnection.

```
Using sqlcmd As New SqlCommand("hyd_top_level_isr", ParentMDI.dbCon)
    With sqlcmd
        .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@part_num", part_num)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@issue", issue)
    End With
    Try
        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As SqlException
        '' Handle exception here
    End Try
End Using
```

Comment: Please see above. Mistakes were made in my original post, made up of a mash of code that I was using in an attempt to fix it...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I think that in SQLCommand you should pass the SQL connection like:

```
Dim sqlcmd As New SqlCommand("hyd_top_level_isr", ParentMDI.dbCon)
```

Secondly, you are not run sqlcmd but sql.executenonquery.

Third, executenonquery is an integer. If you dim a variable:

```
Dim result = sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

What do you get?

Comment: Edit made above, I always use the SQLConnection as above, but was trying using "Using" in my last gasp attempts at trying to solve this.

Comment: And result returns -1

Comment: Are you sure about your connection strings? Secondly, did you open the connection before sqlCommand? If executenonquery returns -1, means that none rows affected. So, your connection strings, or you did not open connection, or sql query is wrong.

Comment: Yes, the connection string is universal. All data in this app comes from the same database, same connection string. Yes the SqlConnection is open, otherwise that would throw an error. SqlQuery is not wrong as it runs in SSMS and would throw an error if incorrect.